# Migrate tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm to Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm migrating a TensorFlow code to Tensorflow 2.1.0.

Here is the original code:

```
conv = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs, out_channels, kernel_size=3, padding='SAME')
conv = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(conv, updates_collections=None, decay=0.99, scale=True, center=True)
conv = tf.nn.relu(conv)
conv = tf.contrib.layers.max_pool2d(conv, 2)
```

And this is what I've done:

```
conv1 = Conv2D(out_channels, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', data_format='channels_last', name=name)(inputs)
conv1 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', data_format="channels_last")(conv1)
#conv = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(conv, updates_collections=None, decay=0.99, scale=True, center=True)
pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), data_format="channels_last")(conv1)
```

My problem is that I don't know what to do with `tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm`.

How can I migrate `tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm` to Tensorflow 2.x?

**UPDATE:**
Using the comment suggestion, I think I have migrated correctly:

```
conv1 = BatchNormalization(momentum=0.99, scale=True, center=True)(conv1)
```

But I'm not sure if `decay` is like `momentum` and I don't know how to set `updates_collections` in the `BatchNormalization` method.

Comment: There is a `BatchNormalization` layer in the same place you got the conv/max pool layers.

Comment: Thanks. Now I need to know how to use the same parameters in this `BatchNormalization`.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this problem when working with a trained model that I was going to fine tune. Just replacing `tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm` with `tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization` like OP did gave me an error whose fix is described below.

The old code looked like this:

```
tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(
    tensor,
    scale=True,
    center=True,
    is_training=self.use_batch_statistics,
    trainable=True,
    data_format=self._data_format,
    updates_collections=None,
)
```

and the updated working code looks like this:

```
tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(
    name="BatchNorm",
    scale=True,
    center=True,
    trainable=True,
)(tensor)
```

I'm unsure if all the keyword arguments I removed are going to be a problem but everything seems to work. Note the `name="BatchNorm"` argument. The layers use a different naming schema so I had to use the `inspect_checkpoint.py` tool to look at the model and find the layer names which happened to be `BatchNorm`.